# How to improve readability of a PGFPlot?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to recreate this image in tikz.

[image]

The plot I've created is:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, pstricks]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\title{Python Notebook}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    lbl/.style = {text=black, anchor=south, sloped},
    lbl1/.style={text=black, anchor=south,sloped},
    dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.6pt,
                  node contents={}}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    xlabel=$x$, x label style={anchor=west}, 
    ylabel=$y$, y label style={anchor=south}, 
    grid=both,
    ytick={-5,-4,...,9},
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, fill=white,
                     inner sep=2pt},
    ymin=-2.5, ymax=6,
    no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={blue, thick}    
             ]

\addplot coordinates{(-1,0) (5,5) } node [near start, lbl] {$y=x+1$};
\addplot coordinates{(-1,-1) (5,4)} node[near start, lbl]{$y=x+0.3$};
\addplot coordinates{(-1,-2) (5, 3)}
            node[near end, lbl] {$y=x-0.8$};

\node at (1,3) [dot,label=right:${(1,3)}$];
\node at (3,4) [dot,label=right:${(3,4)}$];
\node at (2,1) [dot, label=right: ${(2,1)}$];
\node at (4,3) [dot,label=right: ${(4,3)}$];

\end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Fitting a regression Line}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

Referring to Fig \ref{fig:enter-label}.
\end{document}
```

What I trying to do is to improve the readibility of the graph. Specifically:

1. Trying to stretch the graph so all the elements don't stack upon each other
2. Making the font size enough to make it readable on an article class document
3. Other minor tweaks to make the plot more intuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

1. Use a legend, in my opinion, is more readable. You can play with dotted/dashed lines if you do not have colors.
2. Use *correct* lines (let `pgfplots` compute them!)
3. Adjust the limits and the legend position to make the result pleasing.
4. Using `\footnotesize` for fonts should guarantee readability, but *don't scale* the figure; use `width` and `height` to fit in the column, and then repeat point 3.

```latex
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\title{Python Notebook}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        lbl dots/.style = {text=black, fill=white, font=\footnotesize,
        inner sep=0pt},
        dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.6pt,
        node contents={}}
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis equal,
            ymin=-2.5, ymax=5.5,
            xmin=-4, xmax=5.5,
            domain = -2:4, % added
            xlabel=$x$, x label style={anchor=west},
            ylabel=$y$, y label style={anchor=south},
            grid=both,
            ytick={-5,-4,...,9},
            ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, fill=white,
                inner sep=2pt},
            no marks,
            every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
            legend style = {nodes={right, font=\footnotesize}, 
            at={(0.0,0.6)}, anchor=west},
            ]

            \addplot {x+1};
            \addplot {x+0.3};
            \addplot {x-0.8};
            \legend{$y=x+1$, $y=x+0.3$, $y=x-0.8$}

            \node at (1,3) [dot,label={[above, lbl dots]:${(1,3)}$}];
            \node at (3,4) [dot,label={[above left, lbl dots]:${(3,4)}$}];
            \node at (2,1) [dot, label={[right=4pt, lbl dots]:${(2,1)}$}];
            \node at (4,3) [dot,label={[right=4pt, lbl dots]:${(4,3)}$}];

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Fitting a regression Line}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

Referring to Fig \ref{fig:enter-label}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \draw[gray!20] (0,-.5) grid (5,6);
        \draw[thin,-latex] (-.1,0)--(5.6,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[thin,-latex] (0,-1)--(0,6) node[above] () {$y$};
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            \draw[gray] (\i,.1)--(\i,-.1) node[below] () {\i};
        \foreach \i in {-1,0,...,6}
            \draw[gray] (.1,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] () {\i};
        \filldraw[cyan] (1,3) circle(.1);
        \filldraw[cyan] (2,1) circle(.1);
        \filldraw[cyan] (3,4) circle(.1);
        \filldraw[cyan] (4,3) circle(.1);
        \draw [magenta, line width=3pt] plot [domain=-.5:5] (\x,{\x-.8});
        \draw[magenta]  (6,4.2) node () {\large $C:\quad \hat{y}=x-.8$};
        \draw [orange, line width=3pt] plot [domain=-.5:5] (\x,{\x+.3});
        \draw[orange]   (6,5.2) node () {\large $B:\quad \hat{y}=x+.3$};
        \draw [green,line width=3pt] plot [domain=-.5:5] (\x,{\x+1}) ;
        \draw[green]    (6,6) node () {\large $A:\quad \hat{y}=x+1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Option1**: this plot

[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        %\draw[gray!20] (0,-.5) grid (5,6);
        \draw[thin,-latex] (-.1,0)--(5.6,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[thin,-latex] (0,-1)--(0,6) node[above] () {$y$};
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
            \draw[gray] (\i,.1)--(\i,-.1) node[below] () {\i};
        \foreach \i in {-1,0,...,6}
            \draw[gray] (.1,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] () {\i};
        \filldraw[cyan] (1,3) circle(.1);
        \filldraw[cyan] (2,1) circle(.1);
        \filldraw[cyan] (3,4) circle(.1);
        \filldraw[cyan] (4,3) circle(.1);
        
        \draw[magenta,line width=3pt]   (-.5,-1.3)--(5,4.2) node[midway, above,sloped] () {\large $C:\quad \hat{y}=x-.8$};
        
        \draw[orange,line width=3pt]    (-.5,-.2)--(5,5.3) node[midway, above,sloped] () {\large $B:\quad \hat{y}=x+.3$};
                
        \draw[green!50!black,line width=3pt] (-.5,.5)--(5,6) node[midway, above,sloped] () {\large $A:\quad \hat{y}=x+1$};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```